# Фильтрация текста Notepad/Excel

Tags: excel, notepad++

Есть текстовый документ формата ниже:

```
Key: 9HBQN-38WVV-2TYWC-JVQVH-M4HHC
Description: Office16_ProPlusMSDNR_Retail
Sub type: X20-19681
Error code: 0xC004C060
Time: 12/23/2022 7:40:17 PM (GMT+7)

Key: GK7N-PRKJ-8T34-HBDM-RY3P
Description: Office16_ProPlusMSDNR_Retail
Sub type: X20-19681
Error code: 0xC004C008
Time: 12/23/2022 7:40:17 PM (GMT+7)
```

Необходимо с помощью регулярных выражений:

1. Объединить каждые 5 строк в одну (до переноса строк)
2. Удалить все строки содержащие "0xC004C060"
3. Из одной большой строки ранее соединенной в 5, где написано либо "0xC004C008" либо "Online", оставить только сам ключ. Либо хотя бы разъединить их обратно.

Итоговая цель оставить только рабочие ключи из массива (с ошибкой 008 либо пометкой Online)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: после выполнения пунктов 1 и 2 вся предложенная вами в примере информация будет удалена. ну, за исключением 11-й строки.